# Different delimiter in group concat

Tags: mysql, replace, delimiter, group-concat

I have an sql query like this:-

```
 REPLACE(
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
   IF( 
    (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00')    
     && (priority='P5') ,bug_id,'')
     ),',,','' )
   AS exceeded_bugs
  from bugs
  ......
```

The result I got:-

```
exceeded_bugs: ,3743331,3743332,3743333
```

I need different delimiter since, the default delimiter of Group concat is ",". I need to separate the bugs using space or "|" or "-" symbol.

I tried giving :-

```
 REPLACE(
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
   IF( 
    (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '05:00:00')    
    && (priority='P6') ,bug_id,'')
    ) 
    ,SEPARATOR '-' ) 
   AS exceeded_bugs 
  from bugs
  .....
```

I got error:-

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPARATOR '-' ) as exceeded_bugs at line 1

Please help to correct the sql syntax of group concat with a different separator.

Comment: Don't think the comma before SEPARATOR is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont use the comma before SEPARATOR

first you are not including `separator` inside `group_concat` function .

second you are not making anything with replace function

[Take a look here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

EDIT:

```
   REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT( IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') && (priority='P5') ,bug_id,'') SEPARATOR '-'),',,','' ) as exceeded_bugs
```

Comment: any other kind of group concat method?

Comment: The SEPARATOR in that code fragment is within the REPLACE rather than the GROUP_CONCAT (not that any replace is being done)

Comment: i dont know why you using REPLACE  yasmin and you are not replacing anything

Comment: I am using replace function , since the result is showing extra ',,' commas instead of bug ids.

Comment: it is showing the result:-
exceeded_bugs: --3743334---------------------------------

Comment: exceeded_bugs: ,,,3743331,3743332,3743333,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: how you want the result will be?

Comment: exceeded_bugs: 3743331-3743332-3743333

Comment: select sum( IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') && (priority='P5') ,1,0)) P5_time_exceeded,REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT( IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00')    && (priority='P5') ,bug_id,'')),',,','' ) as exceeded_bugs from bugs where bugs.product_id=237 and bugs.resolution  ='FIXED'    and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-16 00:00:00'    and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-18 08:00:00' and bug_status='RESOLVED' \G;

Comment: *************************** 1. row ***************************
P5_time_exceeded: 3
   exceeded_bugs: ,3743331,3743332,3743333

Comment: actually in this query you are not using separator as i told u

Comment: i have used and i got the result :-

Comment: I have posted my answer. Thanks. Please check Samir

Answer (score 0):

Samir's reply was giving more hyphens in the result. I have slightly modified the query, and got the exact result.

Samir's query:-

```
 select sum( 
    IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') 
    && (priority='P5') ,1,0))   P5_time_exceeded,
    REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT( IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') 
    && (priority='P5') ,bug_id,'') SEPARATOR '-'),',,','' ) as exceeded_bugs 
    from bugs 
     ......
```

Result I got:-

```
P5_time_exceeded: 3                                                                                                                                  
exceeded_bugs: ---3743331-3743332-3743333--------------------------                                                                           
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Modified query**

```
 select sum( 
   IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') 
   && (priority='P5') ,1,0)) P5_time_exceeded,
   REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT( IF( (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00')
   && (priority='P5') ,bug_id,'') SEPARATOR '-'),'---','' ) 
   as exceeded_bugs 
   from bugs 
   where .....
```

Got the exact result:-

```
P5_time_exceeded: 3
   exceeded_bugs: 3743331-3743332-3743333
```

I am replacing the least multiple of repeating sybmol ,,, replaced with a space '', so that, the repeating symbol wont come.

Thanks Samir.

Comment: i just give a guess why you getting much --- is because you have empty values and it concatenated with sperator - so thats why you got many ------------- , it means you have fields empty concat fields empty ..... so i think you should give and condition to dont select empty values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need the REPLACE.

GROUP_CONCAT should ignore NULL fields, but you are putting in empty occurances when you want to ignore one. Instead of using '' try using NULL instead.

Like this:-

```
SELECT SUM( IF( (TIMEDIFF(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') && (priority='P5') ,1,0)) AS P5_time_exceeded,
GROUP_CONCAT( IF( (TIMEDIFF(delta_ts,creation_ts) > '03:00:00') && (priority='P5'), bug_id, NULL) SEPARATOR '-') AS exceeded_bugs 
FROM bugs 
WHERE .....
```